# Why does Xcode use NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]) instead of just @"AppDelegate" or nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've noticed in recent versions of Xcode where ARC is used by default, the main.m file Xcode generates for you when you start a new project uses `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])` as the parameter for the app delegate in UIApplicationMain instead of just `@"AppDelegate"` or even just `nil`

New way:

```
@autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

Old way:

```
  @autoreleasepool {
      int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
      return retVal;
  }
```

I'm just wondering if there is a reason for this? It just seems a bit contrived to me, but I'm hoping to be set straight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a compilation check. It's better if the argument can be checked at compile-time. If it's just a string, it's impossible to check.

Regarding the `nil` argument, the documentation says:

> Specify nil if you load the delegate object from your application’s main nib file.

That supposes you are using a xib file to declare the class of your application delegate. Well, many projects don't. In general, project templates without xib files (e.g. "Empty Application") can't use `nil`.

Comment: Ah, hearing that, it suddenly makes a lot of sense =) Thanks

Comment: Exactly;  the `[AppDelegate class]` forces a link error if the class is renamed or doesn't exist.  The `NSStringFromClass()` is a vestige of the original API that took a string, not a class.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Xcode's new project templates don't use a MainWindow.xib to load the App Delegate, so that's why the App Delegate must be specified here instead of using `nil`.